# How to use regex, switch and trim on python to retrieve a value in a file?

Tags: python, regex, string, file, switching

I have a file with this format:

```
Description 10.01.1
;
;     Find the information here
;
University
    National Cantoon University
Status
    National
Administrator visible
    Disable
    *Enable
Start Edu Fair Event
    Event Only
    *Event and invite user
    Event and staff
Permanently Disable
    *No
    Yes
Order
    Year 2021/Jan-Dec(14543043643)

    Year 2022/Jan-Dec(56486565465)
```

I would like to get the value of each key.
for the example, I want to get the value of `Status` which is `National`
If the value have more than one, then I need to get all the values, example, I need to get the value of `Permanently Disable` which is `*No and Yes` . I have done this in PowerShell, I use regex and trim. But now I need to use it in Python. I am new in python, anyone can help me, I really appreciated. Thank you so much

```
function info
{
    Param($Path, $Values)
    $name = $false
    switch -regex -file $Path
    {
        $Values{ $name = $true; continue }
        '^\s' { if ($name) { $_.Trim() }}
        '^\S' { if ($name) { return }}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

d = dict()
key = ""

# iterate line by line
for line in text.split('\n')[1:]:
    # skip empty line
    try:
        # skip header
        if line[0] == ';':
            continue
        # check whether first character is space
        # no --> key
        if not line[0].isspace():
            key = line
            d[key] = list()
            # print("key: ", line)
        # yes --> value
        else:
            # remove space
            d[key].append(line.strip())
            # print("value: ", line.strip())
    except:
        continue
```

Output:

> ```
> >>> print(d)
> {
>  'University': ['National Cantoon University'], 
>  'Status': ['National'], 
>  'Administrator visible': ['Disable', '*Enable'], 
>  'Start Edu Fair Event': ['Event Only', '*Event and invite user', 'Event and staff'], 
>  'Permanently Disable': ['*No', 'Yes'], 
>  'Order': ['Year 2021/Jan-Dec(14543043643)', 'Year 2022/Jan-Dec(56486565465)']
> }
> ```

Comment: @Cheries I've updated my answer, does it work?

Comment: @JayPeerchai, yeah, it can read the `Order` part. But the other problem is, the header is not always `4`,  it always changed, but it always end with `;` before the content. So, can we identify it as `;` not use static number like 4 ?

Comment: @Cheries you can check if the line begins with `;` using `if line[0] == ';':`. I've updated my answer, please see. Sorry if the answer looks too manual right now. I'm not quite familiar with `RE`.

Comment: so I try to avoid using it.